# Adding EMA with Signal on Smoothed RSI

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add an EMA with Smoothing Line on Cyclic Smoothed RSI. The EMA is pine-script version 5, and the Cyclic Smoothed RSI is version 4. But even if I downgrade the EMA to version 4, I am still having the following error -

> Syntax error: Arguments of input function must be of constant type, or
> 'source' builtin variables.

My code is as follows -

```
//@version=4
study(title="Smoothed Cyclic RSI with EMA", shorttitle="cRSI-EMA")
src = close
domcycle = input(20, minval=10, title="Dominant Cycle Length")
crsi = 0.0
cyclelen = domcycle / 2
vibration = 10
leveling = 10.0
cyclicmemory = domcycle * 2
//set min/max ranges?

h1 = hline(30, color=color.silver, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
h2 = hline(50, color=color.silver, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
h3 = hline(70, color=color.silver, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)

torque = 2.0 / (vibration + 1)
phasingLag = (vibration - 1) / 2.0

up = rma(max(change(src), 0), cyclelen)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), cyclelen)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)
csrsi = torque * (2 * rsi - rsi[phasingLag]) + (1 - torque) * nz(crsi[1])

lmax = -999999.0
lmin = 999999.0
for i = 0 to cyclicmemory - 1 by 1
    if nz(csrsi[i], -999999.0) > lmax
        lmax := nz(csrsi[i])
        lmax
    else
        if nz(csrsi[i], 999999.0) < lmin
            lmin := nz(csrsi[i])
            lmin

mstep = (lmax - lmin) / 100
aperc = leveling / 100

db = 0.0
for steps = 0 to 100 by 1
    testvalue = lmin + mstep * steps
    above = 0
    below = 0
    for m = 0 to cyclicmemory - 1 by 1
        below := below + iff(crsi[m] < testvalue, 1, 0)
        below

    ratio = below / cyclicmemory
    if ratio >= aperc
        db := testvalue
        break
    else
        continue

ub = 0.0
for steps = 0 to 100 by 1
    testvalue = lmax - mstep * steps
    above = 0
    for m = 0 to cyclicmemory - 1 by 1
        above := above + iff(csrsi[m] >= testvalue, 1, 0)
        above

    ratio = above / cyclicmemory
    if ratio >= aperc
        ub := testvalue
        break
    else
        continue

fill(h1, h2, color=color.silver, transp=90)
plot(csrsi, "CS-RSI", color.fuchsia)

//EMA with Signal
//Inputs
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")
esrc = input(csrsi, title="Source")
smoothingLength = input(title = "Length", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing")
offset = input(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
//Calculation
out = ema(esrc, len)
smoothingLine = sma(out, smoothingLength)
//Plotting
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.green, offset=offset)
plot(smoothingLine, title="Smoothing Line", color=color.red, offset=offset, display=display.none)
```

I would be grateful if anyone here can fix this code either in version 4 or 5 of pine-script.
The error in version 5 is regarding **iff()** function. And the error is as follows -

> line 44: Could not find function or function reference 'iff'.

Please help me fix this. Thanks for your time. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change below line and remove input option on source

```
esrc = input(csrsi, title="Source")
```

To

```
esrc = csrsi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change this code sentence:

```
esrc = input(csrsi, title="Source")
```

To

```
esrc = input(crsi, title="Source")
```

Worked for me!